# Mongoose schema optional with validation

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose

Given a Schema like this:

```
new Schema(
    {
      someData: {
        someString: {
          required: false,
          maxlength: 400,
          type: String
        }
        otherData: {
          required: true,
          type: String
        }
});
```

`someString` is optional but has a validation to check if it's length is below 400.

If I'm given an invalid length string (>400) would this object still be saved but without the `someString` or would this throw an error? If this throws an error how can I change the schema so that the object will still get saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will throw an error without saving the document.

Let's say we have this schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const studentSchema = new Schema({
  someData: {
    someString: {
      required: false,
      maxlength: 5,
      type: String
    },
    otherData: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);
```

And this post route:

```
const Student = require("../models/student");

router.post("/students", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await Student.create(req.body);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
      return res.status(400).send(err.errors);
    }
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

When we send a bad request it will give ValidationError where we can read the error details from `err.errors`.

Request Body:

```
{
  "someData": {
    "someString": "123456",
    "otherData": "other"
  }
}
```

The response will be:

```
{
    "someData.someString": {
        "message": "Path `someData.someString` (`123456`) is longer than the maximum allowed length (5).",
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `someData.someString` (`123456`) is longer than the maximum allowed length (5).",
            "type": "maxlength",
            "maxlength": 5,
            "path": "someData.someString",
            "value": "123456"
        },
        "kind": "maxlength",
        "path": "someData.someString",
        "value": "123456"
    }
}
```

You can resolve this by removing the `maxlength` option, or check the field's length in your route, and if it's length is bigger than the specified maxlength, you can substr it so that it doesn't result in error.

```js
router.post("/students", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let doc = req.body;

    if (doc.someData && doc.someData.someString && doc.someData.someString.length > 5) {
      doc.someData.someString = doc.someData.someString.substring(0, 5);
    }

    const result = await Student.create(doc);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
      return res.status(400).send(err.errors);
    }
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it truly optional? As in - if the validation fails and it is optional still save the rest?

Comment: @K41F4r  I guess there may be some way, by the way why do you just remove the `maxlength` otion?

Comment: On the one hand - I want to limit the input for this field, on the other - I only need it if its available and won't take too much space in the db

Comment: @K41F4r  you can substr the field if it's length exceeds the maxlength, this way no error occurs and the field is also saved.

Comment: @K41F4r I updated the answer to show how to substr the field if it exceeds maxlength. I guess this is the best way. You can put the maxlength's value into a common file, and use it in your schema and route so that it could be easy to manage.